# Is Round decision affected by KO or TKO?

Tags: boxing

If a boxer wins by KO or TKO, then the rounds won by the boxer and the opponent still count? If I bet on who wins the rounds and one of them wins by KO or TKO, then if my round prediction is right will I win that bet?

Answer (score 1):

The normal way that [round betting](https://www.sportsbettingdime.com/guides/how-to/round-betting/) works is that it allows you to bet on what round will end the fight.  So third round Tyson would be a bet that the boxer named Tyson would win in the third round.  They normally allow for either picking a specific round or a group of rounds (e.g. first four rounds).  [Another source](https://www.sports-king.com/dictionary.php?q=round-betting) saying the same thing.  [A third](https://www.bettingbrain.com/sports-bet/boxing-betting/).  [A fourth](https://www.bettingsite.org/boxing/bets/).  Found by searching for ["boxing bet on who wins a specific round"](https://www.google.com/search?q=boxing+bet+on+who+wins+a+specific+round).

With round betting, you are mostly betting on a knockout (possibly technical), although you'd also win on a submission.  Because a judge's decision wouldn't occur before the completion of the fight.  It is also possible to bet on the method of victory as well as the round.

If you make a standard round bet on a particular fighter in a round and that fighter wins in that round, you will win.  If the fighter wins in a different round or loses but wins that round on points, you will lose.

While it is possible that some bookmaker is accepting bets on the points winner of the round, there would be no standard way to handle such a bet.  Because that's not a standard bet.  So you would in fact have to ask the bookmaker for the specifics in that case.  They might do anything from paying off on the bet (if they feel a knockout wins the round in which it occurs) through refunding your money (because no decision on points) to keeping it (after all if the fighter won by knockout, they didn't win the round on points).  You should establish that before placing the bet, preferably in writing.